# Is it Possible to Randomize an Animation in CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

The following animation is run over three different elements.

How could I randomize the animation such that they occur at different times?

```
@keyframes shine{
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
    transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
    transition-property: left, top, opacity;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/1186/

Also, there appears to be a delay between the animations.  How can I speed up the duration between animations without increasing the speed of the transition itself?

I have tried adding more keyframes but it doesn't seem to increase the time between animations.

Comment: You can use javascript to generate a random number and then apply it as a style, there are also CSS alternatives such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) with modules allowing you to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different animation-delay and animation-duration values for each button like below:

```css
/**
 * Icon
 */

.icon {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  margin: 25px 0 25px 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.icon:nth-child(1) { background: cornflowerblue; }
.icon:nth-child(2) { background: salmon; }
.icon:nth-child(3) { background: gray; }

/**
 * The "shine" element
 */

.icon:after {
  
  animation: shine 1s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -110%;
  left: -210%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 77%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 92%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
}

.icon:nth-child(1):after { animation-delay: .1s; }
.icon:nth-child(2):after { animation-delay: .3s; }
.icon:nth-child(3):after { animation-delay: .5s; }

/* Hover state - trigger effect */


/* Active state */



@keyframes shine{
  60% {
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="icon">let</a>
<a href="#" class="icon">it</a>
<a href="#" class="icon">shine</a>

<!--
Forked by:
Nicolas Gallagher - http://jsfiddle.net/KbNq7/
Chris Coyier - http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/hk6z9/1/
-->
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!  :)  However, there still seems to be a delay between the animations; do you know of any way to make the effect more dramatic by making the shine animation occur more frequently (not to be confused with faster).

Comment: Check out snippset now. You set the shine move in the first 10% of animation and opacity change in the last 90%, that's why there was a big delay between next movements, just change the % of animation step in @keyframes scope and animation-duration time to set intended result.